# insert data in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, insert

Here, in my core data two entity Resgistration & Unique and relationship name is roshan, relationship is one to one.
i try to insert data but code is so lengthy any one help to create short code for perform insert data in core data.

```
- (IBAction)submitData:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];
    Resgistration *newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Unique *number = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unique" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //number = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unique" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [number setValue:_numberText.text forKey:@"number"];
    [number setValue:_studyText.text forKey:@"study"];
    NSMutableSet *roshanSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [roshanSet addObject:number];
    [newContact addRoshan:roshanSet];
    [newContact setValue:number forKey:@"roshan"];
    //[newContact setValue:_numberText.text forKey:@"number"];
    [newContact setValue:_nameText.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newContact setValue:_addressText.text forKey:@"address"];
    [newContact setValue:_emailText.text forKey:@"email"];
    [newContact setValue:_othernoText.text forKey:@"otheNo"];
    [newContact setValue:_hobbyText.text forKey:@"hobby"];
    [newContact setValue:_contactText.text forKey:@"contact"];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

    _nameText.text = @"";
    _addressText.text = @"";
    _emailText.text = @"";
    _othernoText.text = @"";
    _hobbyText.text = @"";
    _contactText.text = @"";
    _numberText.text = @"";

    TableViewController *table = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
}
```

Unique+CoreDataClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Resgistration;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Unique : NSManagedObject

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "Unique+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

Unique+CoreDataClass.m

```
#import "Unique+CoreDataClass.h"
#import "Resgistration+CoreDataClass.h"
@implementation Unique

@end
```

Resgistration+CoreDataClass.h

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Unique;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Resgistration : NSManagedObject

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "Resgistration+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

Resgistration+CoreDataClass.m

```
#import "Resgistration+CoreDataClass.h"
#import "Unique+CoreDataClass.h"
@implementation Resgistration

@end
```

Comment: post your Unique and Resgistration classes code

Comment: it's my NSMAnagedObject Subclass. Check updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you should do it just a little better, but first you need to add those properties in class definition for Resgistration and Unique, as you did in core data model

```
- (IBAction)submitData:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];
    Resgistration *newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Resgistration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Unique *number = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unique" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //number = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Unique" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    number.number = _numberText.text;
    number.study = _studyText.text;
    NSMutableSet *roshanSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [roshanSet addObject:number];
    [newContact addRoshan:roshanSet];
    newContact.roshan = number;
    newContact.name = _nameText.text;
    newContact.address = _addressText.text;
    newContact.email = _emailText.text;
    newContact.otheNo = _othernoText.text;
    newContact.hobby = _hobbyText.text;
    newContact.contact = _contactText.text;
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

    if(error == nil)
    {
        _nameText.text = @"";
        _addressText.text = @"";
        _emailText.text = @"";
        _othernoText.text = @"";
        _hobbyText.text = @"";
        _contactText.text = @"";
        _numberText.text = @"";

        TableViewController *table = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: each statement is necessary, no magic way to reduce code, you can simplify statements in that way

Comment: happy coding :)

Comment: Hey, in this number value is not inserted in core data. tableview in show null value.

Comment: create another question and post the TableViewController source code and share link here, so I can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148982/discussion-between-gangani-roshan-and-ddb).